# How do I add Bookmark option in WebView?

Tags: android, webview, bookmarks

I am new to Android app development, I have a simple app which works on WebView to open a website. I want to add "bookmark this webpage" option in my app but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

You can add any button to your app. Or if you are using Toolbar you can add bookmark button to your options and you can save the page url to Sqllite database or any other storage. There are many other ways also.

you can have a look at the following links-

[First-](https://github.com/darvin/zirco-browser) [Second-](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html)

I hope this would help you.

Well you can create a class for that extends SQLLiteOpenHleper. This provides functionality for accessing sqllite database-
You can refer to [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) link for SQlLite..

And you can create a query for creating a table having columns like id, bookmark name and bookmark url.

You can also add some functions for setting name and url, getting name and urls etc.

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: I think I'l stick to saving the page url to Sqllite database. Can you give me a basic idea of saving urls to SQlite database.